# How to insert data with automatic value to createdDate and updatedDate using Spring, Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I want to insert data with automatic insertion of created_at date time and respective updated_at date time.

I have a pojo as:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Basic(optional = false)
@CreationTimestamp
@Column(name = "created_at")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date createdAt;

@UpdateTimestamp
@Column(name = "updated_at")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date updatedAt;
```

And in my database, I have used DATETIME as a type for created_at and updated_at. But I am not being able to insert data rather it gives an error message **not-null property references a null or transient value: com.project.test.entity.Stamp.createdAt.**

I want to know the proper way to define my database schema for created_at and updated_at DateTime field to make it generate automatically.

Comment: Change your column in mysql to timestamp: `ALTER TABLE yourTable CHANGE COLUMN created_at created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT now()`; same for `updated_at` but without the default now(). Anyways, if you are using hibernate why did you create your database? Why didn't you let the hibernate do it for you ?

Comment: I have tried changing DATETIME to TIMESTAMP type and Default value to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP but still same problem. And same with the updated_at only change in Extra field as on_update_current_timestamp and Default value = None. But no luck with my problem. @JorgeCampos

Answer (score 9):

You can do something like below.

1) initialize your created and updated date using **new Date()** :

```
@Basic(optional = false)
@CreationTimestamp
@Column(name = "created_at")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date createdAt = new Date(); // initialize created date

@UpdateTimestamp
@Column(name = "updated_at")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date updatedAt = new Date(); // initialize updated date
```

2) and provide your setter method for updated date by **new Date()**, without passing any value to it :

```
@PreUpdate
public void setUpdatedAt() {  
    this.updatedAt= new Date(); 
}
```

Comment: can you help me with database schema for defining createdAt and updateAt...currently i am using TIMESTAMP with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as default value for createdAt and TIMESTAMP with Null value YES and on_update_current_timestamp as extra field...how to integrate your code to match all the function relating to update function as well...coz with this code update is not working...@Raju Sharma

Comment: Update is not working ? can you please update and let us know what you have tried with entity and database in question?  B/W, you could use Null value No to createdAt with type as Timestamp and Set default value as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , Null value to No and the attribute to on_update_current_timestamp for updateAt. thus you need to just insert the createdAt date from your code and database will set the updateAt to modified datetime

Comment: I just notice that both columns are inserted while a new row created but this is not actual fact as I think. `created_at` column will be filled when row generated. On the other hand, `updated_at` will be filled when any of the columns is changed. Am I right?

Answer (score 3):

Edited to include MySQL table information.

If you want your source of truth to be the database you can use [@Generated](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/) and allow the database to set the create update timestamp.

```
@Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "created_at")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date createdAt;

@Generated(GenerationTime.ALWAYS)
@Column(name = "updated_at")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date updatedAt;
```

This is for the MYSQL database you need set the update the DEFAULT and [ON UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html) for the column.

```
 createdAt TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 updatedAt TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: Hibernate update operation is not functionning here...public void updateName(Stamp s) {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.update(s);
        session.close();
    }

Comment: Lets do some debugging and make sure the database is doing what you think it should. Can you do a basic insert into the table and make sure that createAt and updateAt are set correctly. After than do a simple update and make sure the updatedAt is updated. Let make sure the database is correctl.