# not-null property references a null or transient value : com.project.test.entity.Stamp.createdAt

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a simple application to perform and update operation using spring mvc and hibernate. But i am getting error. I want to have createdAt and updatedAt date time in my data entry. So how can i achieve this.

POJO:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@CreationTimestamp
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "created_at")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date createdAt;

@UpdateTimestamp
@Column(name = "updated_at")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date updatedAt;
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class HomeController {
    @Autowired
    private NameDao nDao;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getIndex(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("message", "Welcome to Spring");
        model.addAttribute("sL", nDao.getAll());
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addName(Model model, @ModelAttribute Stamp s){
        nDao.addName(s);    
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/update/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getUpdate(@PathVariable int id, Model model){
        Stamp st = (Stamp) nDao.getById(id);
        model.addAttribute("s", st);
        return "update";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/update/{id}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String postUpdate(@ModelAttribute Stamp s){
        nDao.updateName(s);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

Index.jsp:

```
<form method = "post" action="${SITE_URL}/">
        <div>
            <label>Name: </label><input type="text" name="name">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <h3>List...</h3>
    <c:forEach var="sl" items="${sL}">
    <li>${sl.name}&nbsp;${sl.createdAt}&nbsp;${sl.updatedAt}<a href="${SITE_URL}/detail/${sl.id}">Detail</a><a href="${SITE_URL}/update/${sl.id}">Update</a></li>
    </c:forEach>
```

Update.jsp:

```
<h1>Update Here...</h1>
    <form method = "post">
        <div>
            <label>Name: </label><input type="text" value="${s.name}" name="name">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

I could not save the data into database. **not-null property references a null or transient value : com.project.test.entity.Stamp.createdAt** error. What is the problem here.

My database schema is:
[image]

Comment: Please add your DDL for the table.

Comment: there you go...i missed to post the image early...@mdeterman

Comment: One of two options to fix. Update update column updated_at by adding NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP or in your Entity Class remove @Basic(optional=true) [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46504448/how-to-insert-data-with-automatic-value-to-createddate-and-updateddate-using-spr/46504840#46504840)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have null values in your database table.

In your Database updatedAt may be null but you set the JPA property not optional. This is inconsistent.

Remove the @Basic(optional = false) annotation on updatedAt attribute because this attribute is null on insert. Am I right?

Comment: yes, please review the question. I have provided my database schema picture.